# Effective lower bound for class numbers of cyclotomic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, effective-results, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$ with class number $h=h^+h^-$, where as usual $h^+$ is the class number of  the maximal real subfield of $K$. My question is whether there is an effective lower bound for $h$ (which I imagine would be given through one for $h^-)$. I've seen upper bounds for $h^-$ (e.g. [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2044019)), as well as an asymptotic formula (e.g. [here](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/petridis/kummerpublished.pdf)).

Comment: Lower bounds are $h^+ \ge 1$ and $h^- \ge (2\pi)^{-p/2}p^{(p-25)/4}$ where the latter holds for $p > 200$ (can be found in Lang, Cyclotomic fields). 

Comment: Related to the original question, are there bounds for the prime-to-$p$ part of $h^-$? 

Comment: I would be interested by the same question for imaginary quadratic fields. Is there anything known?

Comment: @Bernikov:  There's a lot to be said on that front.  A good starting point is Goldfeld's "THE GAUSS CLASS NUMBER PROBLEM FOR IMAGINARY QUADRATIC FIELDS".



Comment: The link in seems to be dead, but using the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506153717/http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/petridis/kummerpublished.pdf) on can check that it was a link to the paper M.Ram Murty, Yiannis N Petridis: On Kummer's conjecture; DOI: [10.1006/jnth.2001.2667](https://doi.org/10.1006/jnth.2001.2667).